# Как проверить что строка состоит не из одних только пробелов без использования RegExp?

Tags: javascript

Как проверить что строка состоит не из одних только пробелов без использования RegExp?

Comment: какие символы ты хочешь считать пробелами? В твоем прошлом вопросе было перечислено довольно много символов, которые считаются пробельными.

Comment: @Grundy Просто обычный пробел " ", он же `U+0020`

Answer (score 1):

```
function check(s){
  if (s==='') return 'Пустая строка';
  if (s.trim() != '') return 'Строка содержит не пробелы';
  return 'В строке только пробелы';
}
```

Comment: Сдаётся мне что внутри `trim()` те же самые регулярки.

Comment: @Khipster, _Сдаётся мне что внутри trim() те же самые регулярки._ - зависит от конкретной реализации. В спецификации просто написано, что возвращает копию строки без лидирующих и оканчивающих пробелов

Comment: @Khipster, s.trim() можно с лёгкостью заменить на s.replace(' ',''), результат будет тем же.

Comment: @gimntut Без регулярки все пробелы не заменишь.

Comment: Да, вечно я путаю поведение разных языков. В JS вместо replace нужно использовать такую конструкцию: s.split(' ').join('')